# Does WSO2 API Manager 1.8 supports the integration with HSM SafeNet Luna?

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, hsm

We have HSM (i.e. SafeNet Luna) and would like to levarage it for API Key Management instead of WSO2 API Key Manager. I would like know whether WSO2 API Manager 1.8 supports integration with SafeNet Luna HSM. If yes, can you please provide the documentation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager 1.8 does NOT suport integration with SafeNet Luna HSM